# Passing listView row positions through Intents to another class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-intent

I'm wondering how to pass a row position(pos) value from, say, a CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE list Activity(A) to another Activity(B) using Intents? (I want to change ActivityB to show another list depending on what row in ActivityA is clicked).  Here's my code:

```
    final ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(
             new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                  @Override
                  public final void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View cell, int position, long id) {



                      Intent Courses = new Intent(this, ExpandableList.class);
                       Courses.putExtra(//I'm not sure what to put in here//)
             });



    private static final String[] GENRES = new String[] {"Barre","Buffumville","Hodges","Newton Hill"};

}
```

THANKS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Courses.putExtra("position",position);
```

Then to get the position in the next activity:

```
getIntent.getExtras().getInt("position");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the position through the intent putExtra.

please see below Code.

```
 Intent Courses = new Intent(this, ExpandableList.class);
 Courses.putExtra("position",position)
 startActivity(Courses);
```

Now you can get this value in another activity like this.

```
 getIntent.getExtras().getInt("position");
```

It will return the integer position you passed from the first activity.